# How to get this.$el of a component correctly, in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component, its template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <slot />
</template>
```

The function I'm trying to make, is about `resize-observer-polyfill`.
I'm trying to get `this.$el` in `mounted()`, then create an instance of `ResizeObserver`.

But the problem is, if the content of slot is an `async-component`, then I cannot get `this.$el` correctly.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

In Vue 3, you can use a [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html):

```html
<template>
  <div ref="el"></div>
</template>
```

```js
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const el = ref(null);

    // Not available until the component mounts:
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(el.value)
    })
      
    return {
      el
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is this the new recommended way to go about this.$el in Vue3?

Comment: @Tom Yes.  In Vue 3, there may be multiple root elements so `this.$el` would be ambiguous.

Comment: It is being said here it is the recommended way: https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#el

Comment: @sbnc.eu - Yeah, it says using refs instead of `$el` is recommended.